# why is that using a document fragment can improve performance?

Tags: javascript, html

See the  codes below. Insert nodes into the page.

```
var el;
var i = 0;
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

while (i < 10000) {
    el = document.createElement('p');
    el.innerText = 'This is item number ' + i;
    fragment.appendChild(el);
    i++; 
}

body.appendChild(fragment);
```

vs

```
var el;
var i = 0;
var body = document.querySelector('body');

while (i < 10000) {
    el = document.createElement('p');
    el.innerText = 'This is item number ' + i;
    body.appendChild(el);
    i++; 
}
```

As I know, JS excution would block the rendering process. The rendering process should begin right after the JS excution. I think all the newly inserted nodes were rendered at once even though the container appendChilds each node.
How does using a fragment avoid reflows and improve performance?
It's not a appendChild-render-appendChild-render process.

Comment: One could copy the whole paragraph from MDN for an answer but I don't think this is appropriate to do so without further explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment

Comment: In short - document fragments are not part of the DOM. So there is nothing layout/render-related in the fragments. And HTML elements have zero dimensions until they are attached to the DOM. And since there is no reflow/repaint while you are working with document fragments - they are essentially just regular JavaScript objects like your own objects.